# SQL Foreign key error 1215

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a foreign key on my table but i don't why this failed.I am doing with MySQL Workbench

```
    ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`listacompartidasprogramas` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `program_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`programs` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

**listacompartidasprogramas** description of table

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
program_id  varchar(100)    NO  MUL     
listacompartida_id  int(10) YES MUL
```

**programs** table description

```
id  varchar(100)    NO  PRI     
channel_id  varchar(50) YES         
channel_name    varchar(45) YES         
titulo  varchar(150)    YES
```

I know that their is a id of varchar(100). For this it's ok. (Please don't comment). I have checked that id varchar **collation** type is **utf8 - utf8_bin** on both tables.

I have tried to change **ON DELETE NOT NULL** but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Re-try running the alter table and after the error message run the `show engine innodb status` statement and share the exact cause of the error with us.

Answer (score 0):

To find the specific error, run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and then look at the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.